# Neo4j list all nodes with it's parent properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Assume I have this model in neo4j:

```
          (n2) -> (n3)-> (n9)
           /\
           |
   (n4)<-(n1)->(n5)->(n6)
    |            |
    \/           \/ 
    (n7)         (n8)
```

All nodes have `firstname` and `lastname` properties. 
Is there any cypher to list all nodes with it's parent `firstname` and `lastname`.
Something like this:

```
{ 
  {
     firstname: "n1 name",
     lastname: "n1 last name" 
     parent: {}
  }, 
  {
     firstname: "n2 name",
     lastname: "n2 last name" 
     parent: {
         firstname: "n1 name",
         lastname: "n1 last name" 
     }
  }, 
  {
     firstname: "n3 name",
     lastname: "n3 last name" 
     parent: {
         firstname: "n2 name",
         lastname: "n2 last name" 
     }
  }, 
   .
   .
   .
  {
     firstname: "n9 name",
     lastname: "n9 last name" 
     parent: {
         firstname: "n3 name",
         lastname: "n3 last name" 
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can try this, assuming these are all :N nodes.

```
MATCH (n:N)
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent)-->(n)
RETURN collect(n {.*, parent}) as nodes
```

This uses map projection for each `n` node to show its properties, as well as the properties of the parent node, if it exists. If you only need `firstname` and `lastname` properties, then you can explicitly list them in the map projection like so:

```
MATCH (n:N)
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent)-->(n)
RETURN collect(n {n.firstname, n.lastname, parent {parent.firstname, parent.lastname}}) as nodes
```